# Public keys not available, can't use apt-update

Tags: debian, terminal

I'm getting a lot of errors like this:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. 
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian stretch-updates 
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key 
is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
```

Tried to add the keys manually using:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553
```

and it says imported/processed but I still get the same errors.

Comment: You should clarify in the question which operating system it is that you are actually using, Ubuntu or Debian.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest these:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```